# Can I use Google Maps API to create a Facebook Application?

Tags: facebook, google-maps

Could I use Google Maps API to create a Facebook Application? If so, what is the most efficient method to go about doing this? If not Google Maps, how about Bing Maps API or Openstreetmaps?

Comment: Are you asking from a technical concern, or licensing? Facebook have no policies preventing you from using any of these services as part of an application.

Answer (score 2):

On a technical level you should be able to use the javascript API. You can read up on it at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html

However, check the API licensing carefully. If you intend to charge for your app, or depending on what you plan to track, you may have to purchase the business license which is $10k (no exceptions, whether profitable or not)

Answer (score 1):

I did this long time back. I created an application which was embedded inside facebook and it used google maps API. 
And I guess these things will always work because facebook and google provide service through set of APIs. And they are independent of each other